# Video conversion on different server than app server

Tags: php, laravel, video, ftp, ffmpeg

I've got my application running on server A.

When a user uploads a video via that application, the video should be transferred via FTP to another server B. I don't know how to make something like this work:

- User uploads a video (like `.avi`, `.webm`, `.mkv`)
- Application puts it on the FTP server
- FTP server converts that video to `.mp4`

I've tried using FFmpeg on PHP, but it executes only on the server where the application is located, but I need it to run on the FTP server.

How can I make it work like that?

Comment: I have made some edits to your question trying to make it more understandable. Please have a look to see if this reflects what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. You could add a row to some `uploaded_videos` table after uploading file to a remote server. On a remote server you could run scheduler (using Cron) which is checks for a new unconverted videos every 20 minutes, for example. If unconverted videos exist, it runs a `ffmpeg` task. It converts video, updates table `uploaded_videos` and marks it as `converted`.

Or you could create simple RESTful service on a remote server which will listen for all commands from main server.